# non-Borel set with Tonelli like property

Tags: measure-theory

I am looking for an example of a non-Borel set $C \subseteq \mathbb{R}^2$ such that :

i) $C_x = \{y: (x,y) \in C \} \in \mathcal{B} (R)$ and $C^y= \{ x : (x,y) \in C \} \in \mathcal{B}(R)$ for all $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$

ii) The functions $x \mapsto \lambda (C_x)  $ and $y \mapsto \lambda (C^y) $ are Borel measurables and
$\int \lambda (C_x) d\lambda(x) = \int \lambda(C^y) d \lambda(y)$

I tried the area under the graph of the Cantor function but does not work.

Comment: $\{(x,x): x\in A\}$ where $A$ is a non-Borel set on $\mathbb R$.

Comment: I have posted a detailed answer to your question. Please, let me know if you have any question regarding my answer. If my answer provides relevant / helpful information regarding your question, please,  upvote it. If my answer actualy answers your question, accept it too, please. To upvote, click the triangle **pointing upward above the number** (of votes) in front of the question. To accept the answer, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.

Comment: It was very useful. I upvoted but forgot to accept. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the function $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ defined by $f(x)=(x,x)$.
It is immediate that $f$ is continuous and so Borel-measurable.

Let $E\subseteq \mathbb{R}$ be a non-Borel subset of $\mathbb{R}$. Define $C=\{(x,x)\in \mathbb{R}^2 : x \in E \}$.

> Claim: $C$ is a non-Borel subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$.

**Proof**: Suppose $C$ is a Borel  subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$. Since $f$ is Borel-measurable, and $E=f^{-1}(C)$, we have that $E$ is a Borel subset of $\mathbb{R}$. Contradiction. $\square$

Now, note that, for all $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$, $C_x = \{y: (x,y) \in C \} =\{ x \}\in \mathcal{B} (R)$ and $C^y= \{ x : (x,y) \in C \} = \{ y \} \in \mathcal{B}(R)$.

Moreover, The functions $x \mapsto \lambda (C_x)=0  $ and $y \mapsto \lambda (C^y)=0 $ are are Borel measurables and
$$\int \lambda (C_x) d\lambda(x) = 0 = \int \lambda(C^y) d \lambda(y)$$